# Asp.Net Mvc Web App PowerBI Login HRESULT E_FAIL Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, powerbi

I am trying to have a single sign-in web app through azure that has an initial Microsoft login and then no second login. At the moment I am just trying to get 2 logins to work but when running locally I can get the app to work and show the Power BI reports using a dual login. But whenever I publish the app up to the Azure host and I try to access the power BI page instead of having a Microsoft popup to log in it just suffers from this error.

```
    [COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.RunAsyncTask(Task`1 task) +89
   MultiTenantWebApp.Controllers.PowerBiController.Autenticate() in C:\Users\G4Fro\Source\Repos\Intern\MultiTenantWebApp\MultiTenantWebApp\Controllers\PowerBiController.cs:165
   MultiTenantWebApp.Controllers.PowerBiController.MakeGroupDictionary() in C:\Users\G4Fro\Source\Repos\Intern\MultiTenantWebApp\MultiTenantWebApp\Controllers\PowerBiController.cs:64
   MultiTenantWebApp.Controllers.PowerBiController.EmbedReport() in C:\Users\G4Fro\Source\Repos\Intern\MultiTenantWebApp\MultiTenantWebApp\Controllers\PowerBiController.cs:32
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +169
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +577
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have no idea why it works offline but not online and I don't know how to understand the stack trace

This is the Authentication code

```
private void Authenticate()
        {
            string clientID = ""; // We have our client ID here that was created in power BI dev apps
            string redirectUri = "https://localhost:44367/";
            string resourceUri = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
            string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";

            if (token == null)
            {
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
                token = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri)).AccessToken;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

> HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> have no idea why it works offline but not online and I don't know how to understand the stack trace

According to the exception, it seems that you application try to access to out-of-process COM in the WebApp, but it is restricted in the [Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

If it is restricted in the WebApp and Cloudservice is possible, please have try to use Cloudservice. About how to Migrate and Publish a Web Application to an Azure Cloud Service from Visual Studio, we could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service).

Comment: Yea from that link says it seems like it would be restricted but I don't know how to figure out if it is and our current azure subscription doesn't have cloud services so we might need to upgrade that then

Comment: `I don't know how to figure out if it is`.  We can't do that with WebApp, it is not allowed us to do that.  CloudService may be a choice.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error at the moment and I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact that my azure app does not have the "Access the directory as the signed-in user" permission, since I am accessing Power BI as a master user as in the" App owns data" scenario.

[image]

#### Notes:

- I only get this error when I unwind the aggregate exception. Otherwise the error message is "One or more errors occurred." Here is a good link on that: [Flattening of Aggregate Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872995/flattening-of-aggregateexceptions-for-processing/46732837)
- It *looks* like I have the permission, and that I have the rights to grant it, but when I click on the `Grant permissions` icon I get an error message saying I cannot grant that permission myself.
- In fact the Azure documentation is clear here that you can grant that permission yourself only for Application Type:`Native App`, not `Web app/API` which is what I have here (so the UI has a display bug). Here is a link to it:[Permission Scope Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes)
- I am still trying to figure out who my "Admin" is so that I can get this permission, so I am not yet sure that this is the whole issue. Will update.

Comment: Any Update on this Bro ?